# If I have a GeoJSON file of a certain city's wards, how would I figure out which ward I'm in based on my lat/long coordinates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, geojson, geocoding

Apologies in advance if this might seem like a silly question with an easy answer, or if its too vague, but I really am very new to the whole Geocoding shabang so I might not be able to ask the best questions yet.

Let's say I have the GeoJSON file for Philadelphia (https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/phl::political-wards/explore?location=39.965479%2C-75.035211%2C11.78). I input a pair of coordinates for the Philadelphia City Hall, for example:
Latitude: 39.953306°
Longitude: -75.163577°. What would I need to do to get back the exact ward those coordinates lie in? In JavaScript (Node.js) ideally but any language would work as long as I understand the logic and steps I'd need to take.

Also, feel free to direct me to any resources/articles/videos/etc that would be useful to help me learn more about this kind of stuff.

Comment: The name of this operation is reverse geocoding. Not sure if ward is part of geo data. I understand that term as relating to administrative divisions.

Comment: Yes, I am indeed talking about wards relating to administrative divisions. I'm trying to figure out if the point (coords) lies within the a certain subsection (ward) of the 2d map, whose GeoJSON file I have access to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a polygon (a mathematical one, what GeoJSON would call a linear ring), and a point, imagine a line from the point to the first coordinate of the polygon.  As you move the end of your line to the second coordinate of the polygon, your line moves by some angle (might be positive, might be negative, might be zero).  Similarly from the second to third and so on.  Add up the angles: if the result is +/-360 degrees, your point is inside the polygon.  If zero, then outside. Search "winding number" for details.

Of course, it would be inefficient to test all polygons, so you make some kind of index of the bounding boxes of the polygons, and only inspect those whose bounding box contains your point, these are called R-trees (there are many variants, and lots of software available for this).